# Customize log file name in code when using hydra for configuration

Tags: python, python-logging

I want to customize the name of the log file, and I am using Hydra for configuration.
Note that I don't mean using Hydra to rename the log file.

I tried the below code, but it ends up Test.log (Test.py is the name of the Python script). What I want is that the name of the log file should be custom_log_file.log. So, how should I change the name of the log file?

```
import logging
import hydra

@hydra.main()
def my_app(_cfg):
    # Customize the logging configuration
    log_file = "custom_log_file.log"
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file)
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    # Rest of your code...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_app()
```